# psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: postgresql

I have access remote postgesql `psql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 1486 postgres`

It's show this error

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 1486?
```

**postgresql.conf** file

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

**pg_hba.conf** file

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0          md5
```

Also apply open **1486 port**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d X.X.X.X  --dport 1486 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s X.X.X.X --sport 1486 -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

It's return same error.

Comment: Make sure that Pg server is up

Comment: make sure selinux isn't blocking you.  confirm that `getenforce` is either `disabled` or `permissive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a canonical answer but here are a few things to try (some of them may not apply / be possible):

- Ping the IP address in question - is the server up at all / reachable? Are there other services on the box that can be reached?
- Connect from a local connection on the server itself, assuming you have console or ssh access
- If you have local access and network based access doesn't work, is unix-domain socket access allowed and if so, does that work?
- Check the port config in postgresql.conf - is it really where you think it is?
- Has the config file been edited since the last server restart? The parameters you listed all require server restarts to take effect.
- Is it actually using the config file you think it is? Running "SHOW config_file;" as superuser will help if you can make a local connection
- What happens is you do telnet  1486? Do you get a network connection or similar error?
- Get a pcap and check what's happening at the network level (wireshark or tcpdump will help)